# Creating a hostgroup from a super-set of hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have two host files with different hosts, hostGroups and super-set in each file like below.

/ets/hostFiles/TestBoxes

```
[TestBox:children]
groupA
groupB

[groupA]
...
...

[groupB]
...
...
```

/ets/hostFile/ProdBoxes

```
[ProdBox:children]
groupPA
groupPB

[groupPA]
...
...

[groupPB]
...
...
```

Now i would like to create a Primary host group with TestBox and ProdBox

Please let me know if this is possible.

Note: This is just an example... I have 100+ files like this. and I want to create primary group with few of the files. `hosts=all` is not my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *constructed* inventory plugin. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory constructed
```

Create the inventory files

```bash
shell> tree inventory/
inventory/
├── 01-TestBoxes
├── 02-ProdBoxes
└── 03-Primary.yml

0 directories, 3 files
```

```bash
shell> cat inventory/01-TestBoxes 
[TestBox:children]
groupA
groupB

[groupA]
host_1

[groupB]
host_2
```

```bash
shell> cat inventory/02-ProdBoxes 
[ProdBox:children]
groupPA
groupPB

[groupPA]
host_P1

[groupPB]
host_P2
```

```bash
shell> cat inventory/03-Primary.yml 
plugin: constructed
groups:
  Primary: (group_names | intersect(['ProdBox', 'TestBox'])) | length > 0
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: Primary
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

reads files from the directory *inventory* in alphabetic order. The file *Primary.yml* creates the group *Primary* from hosts that are members of the groups *ProdBox* and *TestBox*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory pb.yml 

PLAY [Primary] *******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  inventory_hostname: host_1
ok: [host_2] => 
  inventory_hostname: host_2
ok: [host_P1] => 
  inventory_hostname: host_P1
ok: [host_P2] => 
  inventory_hostname: host_P2

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_P1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_P2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Q: ***" I have 100+ files like this. and I want to create primary group with few of the files."***

A: Create links

```bash
shell> tree inventory/
inventory/
├── 01-TestBoxes -> ../hostFiles/TestBoxes
├── 02-ProdBoxes -> ../hostFiles/ProdBoxes
└── 03-Primary.yml
```